# Convert image URL to dataURL - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using react-native-facebook-login in order to get user data. Its returning me the url of the profile picture. when I paste this url in the browser the picture gets downloaded.
Its returning the following string named profile

```
{"id":"10210xxx114564932","name":"Stan Shivam","email":"ansh1602@gmail.com","first_name":"Shivam","last_name":"Stan","age_range":{"min":21},"link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/10210663114564932\/","picture":{"data":{"height":50,"is_silhouette":false,"url":"https:\/\/lookaside.facebook.com\/platform\/profilepic\/?asid=10210663114564932&height=50&width=50&ext=1523007905&hash=AeQ-_PZnt1JTbnth","width":50}},"gender":"male","locale":"en_GB","timezone":5.5,"updated_time":"2018-03-27T18:37:33+0000","verified":true}
```

What I want to do is I want to convert the url to base64 and send it to server. But I am not being able to find some good tut on this.

What I tried so far.

```
getBase64ImageFromUrl = async (imageUrl) => {
    const res = await fetch(imageUrl);
    console.log(res);
    const blob = await res.blob();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
          resolve(reader.result);
      }, false);

      reader.onerror = () => {
        return reject(this);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
  };
```

calling it from constructor

```
this.getBase64ImageFromUrl('https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=10210663114564932&height=50&width=50&ext=1523007763&hash=AeSavHT5oXVEMq4w')
            .then(result => console.log(result))
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

But it gives me res.blob() is not a function.
What exactly do I need to use in order to achive it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this using FileReader. use the following function and pass the url and callback. Thanks

```
export const toDataUrl = (url, callback) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = () => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
          callback(reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
};
```

calling the function

```
toDataUrl('https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=10210663114564932&height=50&width=50&ext=1523007763&hash=AeSavHT5oXVEMq4w', (myBase64) => {
              console.log(myBase64); // myBase64 is the base64 string
            });
```

Comment: if the url is stored on a remote server, like cloud storage, the above solution will not work as it will face the CORS issue.